# I tried to upload and display image using netbeans and wampserver frontend java and backend Mysql but it says to add multipart

Tags: java, jsp

This is my **Web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE sun-web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.0 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://www.sun.com/software/appserver/dtds/sun-web-app_3_0-0.dtd">
<sun-web-app error-url="">
<class-loader delegate="true"/>
<jsp-config>
<property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
  <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
</property>
</jsp-config>
</sun-web-app>
```

This is **changeimage.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="java.io.InputStream"%>
<%           InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file
        // obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
        Part filePart = request.getPart("txtfile");
        filePart.toString();
        if (filePart != null) {
            // prints out some information for debugging
            inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
        }
        String message = "";
        String userid = session.getAttribute("userid").toString();
        int row = DB.Connect.changeImage(userid, inputStream);
        if (row > 0) {
            message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
            System.out.print("message=" + message);
        } else {
            message = "An error has occured";
        }
        session.setAttribute("Message", message);
        // forwards to the message page
       response.sendRedirect("profile.jsp");%>
```

This code is **displayimage.jsp:**

```
<%@page import="java.io.OutputStream"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Blob"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%

          String username = request.getParameter("userid");
         DB.Connect.openConnection();
            String query = "select image  from tbluser where userid = " + username;
            ResultSet rs = DB.Connect.stat.executeQuery(query);


            // clear the response header information.
            response.reset();

            rs.next();
            Blob blb = rs.getBlob(1);
            byte[] bdata = blb.getBytes(1, (int) blb.length());

            // get the response Output stream object to write the content of the file into header
            OutputStream output = response.getOutputStream();

            output.write(bdata);
            output.close();
            // close the obejct of ResultSet
            rs.close();

            // close the connection object..
            DB.Connect.closeConnection();%>
```

This is to **uploadimage.jsp:**

```
<%@include file="header_admin.jsp" %>
<div class="body">
<div >
    <div style="width: 100%;height:300px">
        <div align="center">
            <form action="changeImage.jsp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <%=session.getAttribute("Message")%>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <input type="file" name="txtfile" id="txtfile" class="upload_file"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>

                            <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" class="selected" style="background-color: burlywood"/>

                        </td>
                    </tr>

                </table>




            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
<%@include file="footer_home.jsp" %>
```

This show **Error:**

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request.getPart is called without multipart configuration. Either add a @MultipartConfig to the servlet, or a multipart-config element to web.xml
```

I am trying to add/upload image to database and then display that image from database to profile of admin.